# Graceful shutdown - runlevel 0 scripts not getting called

Tags: linux, runlevel, remote-shutdown

I am working on a client platform which has RHEL 5.0 OS installed with kernel version 2.6.34.12 .

The issue I am facing is that when this system gets a poweroff signal from remote server, it gets shutdown directly without entering into runlevel 0 .

I tried to enter runlevel 0 manually bu applying telinit 0. It's working fine.

I thought this might be an IPMI related problem, as it is the one which gets the signal and do es the needful. In /var/log/messages found that IPMI drivers are initializing properly.

The functionality is working fine when reboot command is issued from system. But on remote signal reception, Its not even entering rc script which calls to change the runlevel.

Now I have no idea where can there be the issue, where should I see?

Thanking you in advance for your future help.

Thanks,
S Parikh

Answer (score 0):

As this is RHEL you can run `sos` and raise that with RHEL support.

What is the `poweroff` signal? IPMI?
Have you got this:

```
yum install OpenIPMI OpenIPMI-tools
chkconfig ipmi on
service ipmi start
```

There is a chance that IPMI have some bugs or you are sending a wrong signal. See if you can update some things as you should not be running RHEL 5.0 any more due to millions of critical patches to it!

Comment: Hi Chris.. I would like to post some logs that I ot regarding IPMI..